# Remote Debugging Azure Function NodeJS Docker in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I would like to debug remote into my nodejs azure function docker container.

Dockerfile:

```
# To enable ssh & remote debugging on app service change the base image to the one below
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:4-node18-appservice
# FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:4-node18

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot 

RUN npm install -g npm@latest && \
    cd /home/site/wwwroot && \
    npm install && \
    npm run build

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true \
    APPSVC_REMOTE_DEBUGGING=TRUE
```

launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Docker NodeJs Attach",
      "type": "docker",
      "request": "attach",
      "processName": "/azure-functions-host/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost",
      "platform": "node",
      "sourceFileMap": {
        "/home/site/wwwroot": "${workspaceFolder}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm starting the container with:

```
docker run -p 8080:80 -t report-service-image
```

My azure function works as expected but the remote debugger is not working.